# Interesting uses of M?

Tags: modeling, m

I know M is a new language from Microsoft that's targeted as a modeling solution but I'm still a bit fuzzy on usage / rationale / advantages. That's why I'm looking for interesting things that people have done with M, so I can understand it better.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's new, as you said, so you'll have a hard time finding thing already done.  Your best bet would probably be to see how Microsoft itself uses the language.